# Hadoop vs Cassandra: Which is better for the following scenario?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, database

There is a situation in our systems in which the user can view and "close" a report. After they close it, the report is moved to a temporary table inside the database where it is kept for 24 hrs, and then moved to an archives table(where the report is stored for next 7 years). At any point during the 7 years, a user can "reopen" the report and work on it. The problem is that archives storage is getting large and finding/reopening reports tend to be time consuming. And I need to get statistics on the archives from time to time(i.e. report dates, clients, average length "opened", etc). I want to use a big data approach but I am not sure  whether to use Hadoop, Cassandra, or something else ? Can someone provide me with some guidelines how to get started and decide on what to use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you archive is large and you'd like to get reports from it, you won't be able to use just Cassandra, as it has no easy means of aggregating the data. You'll end up collocating Hadoop and Cassandra on the same nodes.

From my experience archives (write once - read many) is not the best use case for Cassandra if you're having a lot of writes (we've tried it for a backend for a backup sysyem). Depending on your compaction strategy you'll pay either in space or in iops for having that. Added changes are propagated through the SSTable hierarchies resulting in a lot more writes than the original change.

It is not possible to answer your question in full without knowing other variables: how much hardware (servers, their ram/cpu/hdd/ssd) are you going to allocate? what is the size of each 'report' entry? how many reads / writes you usually serve daily? How large is your archive storage now?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra might work fine.  Keep two tables, reports and reports_archive. Define the schema using a [TTL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html) of 24 hours and 7 years:

```
CREATE TABLE reports (
   ...
) WITH default_time_to_live = 86400;

CREATE TABLE reports_archive (
   ...
) WITH default_time_to_live = 86400 * 365 * 7;
```

Use the new Time Window Compaction Strategy (TWCS) to minimize write amplification.  It could be advantageous to store the report metadata and report binary data in separate tables.

For roll-up analytics, use Spark with Cassandra.  You don't mention the size of your data, but roughly speaking 1-3 TB per Cassandra node should work fine.  Using RF=3 you'll need at least three nodes.